# Compare two things with a third

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-patterns

I am confused if this sentence is correct or do I need to extend it using "performances"

**The performance of method 1 and method 2 is compared with method 3 in this section**

Comment: The sentence is fine as it is, although you might consider making it *…compared with **that of** method 3 …* (using *the performance of* also works.)

Comment: Also, I would consider make it *the **performances** of method 1 and [] 2 **are** compared with*. (Unless they have the same performance.)

Comment: Hi Jason thank you for taking time out to help. Yes there are performance differences between these methods.

Comment: As the part 'in this section' comes at the end, doesn't it mean that method 1 and method 2 are not in this section? Else it should be, In this section, the performance of method 1 and method 2 is compared with method 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From clarification in comments under the question, the sentence can be rephrased in the following way:

> The performances of methods 1 and 2 are compared with that of method 3 in this section.

If method 3 was introduced earlier, and it's only the *comparison* of it that is "in this section," then the last part of the sentence should be moved to the start:

> In this section, the performances of methods 1 and 2 are compared with that of method 3.

---

In both of the revised sentences, the pronoun *that* represents *the performance*. It can be replaced with the longer phrase, but it doesn't have to be.

The reason you want to extend the sentence (as said) is that you want to make it clear it's the *performance* of method 3 that's being compared, not the *entirety* of method 3. It might be assumed that the performance was meant, but the additional precision is useful—especially in what appears to be a technical document, where precision is often required.

Comment: Yes its a technical document, rightly guessed.To clarify a bit more, we already compared t method 1 and method 2 before this point. So now we are trying to say that the two previously compared methods are compared with a third one, especially their performance.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of *respectively* would make it clear

Lexico defines _respectively as: *Separately or individually and in the order already mentioned*

yielding

*The performance of method one and method two respectively is compared with method 3*

Comment: Thanks. Now which advise to follow

Comment: Why not put them all together: _The performances of method one and two respectively are compared with that of method three_